# Which Tensorflow operations do not have GPU support?

Tags: tensorflow

[Tensorflow does not yet have GPU support for the modulus operation.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5a5a25ea3ebef623e07fb9a46419a9df377a37a5/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_gpu_mod.cu.cc#L22)

What other Tensorflow operations lack GPU support and will have to be worked around in a real-time neural network?

Comment: This set of ops changes quite often. Also, some ops have GPU support only for certain data types. I believe there is no list that is actively maintained. Given a specific op, just try running it under `with tf.device('gpu:0')`.